# Which function for several values R

Tags: r, classification

i have a problem with the `which()` function in r.

got an numeric vector [1:349] with different values. But i want to classify them so there are just 4 values.
My idea was the following:

```
KlasFehl <- GP$Fehlstunden #the numeric vector

KFehl30 <- which(KlasFehl == 1|
             KlasFehl == 2|
             KlasFehl == 3|
             KlasFehl == 4|
             .
             .
             .
             KlasFehl == 30)

KlasFehl[KFehl30] <- 30
```

and the same for a Class for the values 0 named 0, 30 to 60 named 60 and the values 60 to 90 named 90.
Thats a lot of work, so i tried it "smarter".

```
 KFehl30 <- which(KlasFehl == 1|2|3|4|5...|30)
```

or

```
 KFehl30 <- which(KlasFehl == (1:30))
```

but r wrote an warning that some numbers aren't used or didn't made it right (e.g. used just the first number)

anyone got an idea how to write it smart and short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `which` function just gives the index of the `TRUE` elements of a Boolean vector. It is rarely needed and often over-used.

The issue you seem to have difficulty with is generating a Boolean with `TRUE` elements if the values in a vector take any one of several different values. One solution is the `%in%` operator:

```
KFehl30 <- KlasFehl %in% (1:30)
```

You can of course convert this Boolean to the index numbers of the `TRUE` elements using `which`, but this is not needed for your (or most) applications.

```
KlasFehl[KFehl30] <- 30
```

will work fine.

Another solution is to use `<=` and `=>` to generate the Boolean vector:

```
KFehl30 <- KlasFehl >= 1 & KlasFehl <= 30
```

Comment: Clearly the correct answer in this case. (I know you will know this so this is just for the future readers who find their way here.) `which` remains useful when using as a subsetting value using "[" if the target column has a lot of NA's that you don't have interest in. That's because it doesn't return a 'numeric'-`NA` (technically an `NaN`) when either of the two sides of the logical expression is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need is not classification, but rather [Binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning). You can accomplish that with the function `cut`. To test it out, I am using the numbers 0 to 90 so that you can see that it produces the correct class for each possibility. Note that since I am starting with 0, 0 is in position 1, 1 is in position 2, etc.

```
KlasFehl = 0:90
KlasFehl = cut(KlasFehl, breaks=c(-1,0,30,60,91), labels=c(0,30,60,90))
KlasFehl
 [1] 0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
[26] 30 30 30 30 30 30 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60
[51] 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90
[76] 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90
Levels: 0 30 60 90
```